# For a convergent series of functions, why do we have $ |R_n(x)| \leq |u_{n+1}(x)| $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> We have: $$ u_n(x) = (-1)^n \frac{ e^{-x \sqrt{n} } }{\sqrt{n}} $$
> We want to prove that the series $ \sum_{n \geq 1 } u_n(x) $ is uniformally convergent on the interval $ ]0, + \infty[ $

---

In the solution to this question, the reasoning goes as follows:

let: $ S (x) = \sum_{n \geq 1 }^{+ \infty} u_n(x) $

We have: $ | S_n(x) - S(x) | = |R_n(x)| \leq |u_{n+1}(x)| $

They determined the supremum of $ |u_{n+1}(x)| $ on $ ]0, + \infty[ $  , and concluded the result.

My questions is why: $ |R_n(x)| \leq |u_{n+1}(x)| $ ?

Thank you.

Comment: This bound works for alternating series in general.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test

Comment: @TravorLZH If the series is not alternating. Do we have always: $|R_n(x)| \geq |u_{n+1}(x)|$ ?

Comment: No, this depends on how fast the sequence $u_n(x)\to0$ as $n\to+\infty$